# Per network settings for a laptop

Tags: networking, laptop, dns, dhcp

I often roam in different networks. Some of those need special settings for DNS or block mails to external mailservers and only accept internal smarthosts. I'm looking for some kind of program where I can make settings based on networks. Say the wireless network with ESSID *Foo* needs a nameserver on address 10.32.5.12 plus one on 8.8.8.8, wired network with ESSID *Bar* takes any nameserver which comes per DHCP and so on. What programs do you know and what are the benefits of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the wireless network with ESSID Foo needs a nameserver on address 10.32.5.12 plus one on 8.8.8.8

You can already configure this in the Network Manager:

[image]

> wired network with ESSID ...

Wired networks don't have ESSIDs

---

Your general solution to *I need to do this random shizzle for this random connection* would be a dispatcher script with Network Manager. Here are some examples:

- [Is it possible to auto-mount sshfs](https://askubuntu.com/a/187132/88802)
- [Multiple IPs for a single WIRELESS NIC](https://askubuntu.com/a/217363/88802)
- [How do I run a simple Zenity script after disconnecting from WiFi?](https://askubuntu.com/a/235367/88802)